# PostGIS geography does not support the "~=" function/operator

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgis

I am trying to save point field in the database via `update_or_create` method but it is giving me this error.

My function to save data:

```
    for city in cities_data:
        obj, created = models.City.objects.update_or_create(
            name = city["name"],
            country = city["country"],
            state = city["state"],
            point = Point(
                float(city["longitude"]),
                float(city["latitude"])   
            ),
            radius = city["radius"],
            is_curated = city["is_curated"],
            is_metro_city = city["is_metro_city"]
        )
        obj.save()
```

Model:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    point = gis_models.PointField(geography=True, null=True)
    is_metro_city = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_curated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    radius = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

when I try to run this I get this error:

```
ValueError: PostGIS geography does not support the "~=" function/operator.
```

I want to know why I am getting this error, I did not find any useful information related to this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27314

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this you can use it like this:

```
        obj, created = models.City.objects.update_or_create(
            **city_data,
            defaults={'point': Point(
                float(city["longitude"]),
                float(city["latitude"])   
            )}
        )
```

I do not know why it does not work that way, but I made it work this way, if you find it out why it does not work you can improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and the problem was that I have a unique together constraint in model's class Meta eg:

```
 class Meta:
        unique_together = 'name', 'geom'
```

After deleting it, the error disappears although you must check by yourself if you need such constraint.

Comment: Well, on some places you cannot remove the constraint.  When you have that kind of constraint, you put the constraint in in the `updated_or_create(name="name", geom="geom", default= {"rest of the values"})`. This is what I learned so far.